# Строка символов в Прологе

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog, visual-prolog

Мной написана программа осуществляющая подсчёт латинских символов на языке Prolog, ниже привожу её код:

```
domains
stroka=string
predicates
nondeterm check(char).
inc(char,integer). 
nondeterm char_count(string,integer).
clauses
check(X):-char_int(X,Code), char_int('A',CodeA), char_int('Z',CodeZ),
Code>=CodeA, Code<=CodeZ.
check(X):-char_int(X,Code), char_int('a',CodeA), char_int('z',CodeZ),
Code>=CodeA, Code<=CodeZ.
inc(Char,1):-check(Char),!.
inc(_,0).
char_count("",0). 
char_count(S,N) :-
          frontchar(S,Char,S1),char_count(S1,N1),
          inc(Char,Inc),N=N1+Inc.      
goal
char_count("B45X2FG0OP",N), write("Symbol count = ",N).
```

Помогите пожалуйста, изменить программу так, чтобы если строка вся латинская, то выводилась на экран, а если в строке есть другие символы например цифры, то вести кол латинских букв

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите пожалуйста, изменить программу так, чтобы если строка вся латинская, то выводилась на экран, а если в строке есть другие символы например цифры, то вести кол латинских букв

Решение:

```
    DOMAINS 
    PREDICATES

        determ is_latin_letter(char).

        determ check_string(string).
        determ check_string(string, integer, integer). %i, i, o

        determ print_result(string, integer).

  CLAUSES

  is_latin_letter(Letter) :-
      upper_lower( UpperCaseLetter, Letter ),
      char_int( UpperCaseLetter, Code),
      char_int('A',CodeA),
      char_int('Z',CodeZ),
      Code >= CodeA, 
      Code <= CodeZ.

  check_string( String ) :-
      check_string( String, 0, LatinLetterCount ),
      print_result( String, LatinLetterCount ).

  check_string("", N, N ).
  check_string( S, N1, N2 ) :-
      frontchar(S, Char, S1),
      if is_latin_letter( Char ) then
          M1 = N1 + 1
      else
          M1 = N1
      end if,
      check_string( S1, M1, N2 ).

  print_result(String, LatinLetterCount ):-
      str_len(String, Len),
      if LatinLetterCount = Len then
          write("Строка латинских букв =", String),
          write("Длина = ", Len).
      else
          write("Количество латинских букв в строке =", LatinLetterCount ).
      end if.

  GOAL

    check_string("B45X2FG0OP"),% Строка, содержащая произвольные символы.
    check_string("ABCdef").    % Строка, содержащая только прописные и строчные латинские буквы.
```

Comment: @Герасимов Станислав Ответ готов.